# NSImage is not displayed on some computer

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage

Did anyone get the same problem? I load a png image using NSImage initWithCotentsFile and display it in a view using drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:. In a very rare case, some of users using mac os x 10.9.2 complain the image is not displayed.

Comment: sometimes those compositing methods will rotate the image by 90d from where you would think... but usually 10.9 and 10.8 should behave the same way... you could also see if anything is output in the logs... like maybe you have a hard coded path that doesn't work if someone is running the app from a different location.

Comment: Is that caused by the retina display? I only have one version of PNG file now.

Comment: that should be pretty easy to isolate... are the users using retina displays the ones that report the image isn't there?

Comment: Re:Grady- I'm using NSBundle pathForResource:ext:inDirectory to load the image. Also the image is not displayed at all.

Comment: That shouldn't really be a problem in an of itself.. you haven't really given us much to go on... have you verified that the NSImage isn't nil? there are lots of reasons that would prevent an image from displaying on screen, problems with the image, with the composite operation, problems with the context.

Comment: I have developed a software which is used by thousands of users. So far two of them sent me a screen shot of image not displaying. Everything is OK for most of users including my developing and testing computer. As I stated in the question, the NSImage is loaded by using initWithCotentsFile, and displayed by using drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction: in the drawRect: of NSView.

Comment: I have tested in a latest retina display mac book pro. It's OK as well.